# Regex to capture words and numbers in separate groups

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need two groups - one to extract words, second - numbers. Example:

```
['| Sofia           | 300']
```

need to extract:

```
Group 1 - Sofia; Group 2 - 300
```

My regex attempt:

```
([a-zA-Z]+[ ]*[a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)
```

I don't understand as to why this doesn't match. I've been reading for 30 minutes now and maybe I can't phrase my issue correctly, but I can't find solution. My thinking here is that each set of parentheses holds a group. The Regex inside them seems to work fine on its own, but when I try to capture 2 groups - it fails. Obviously I am missing something important about multiple group capturing.

Comment: give 2 examples and expected outputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't match because you're not matching the characters *between* "Sofia" and "300".  This would match "Sofia300", but not "Sofia 300" or "Sofia | 300".  Try this:

```
(\w+ *\w+).*?(\d+)
```

(I'm using `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z]` and `\d` instead of `[0-9]` for brevity.)

Comment: So regex doesn't look to match only stuff in (). Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following will give you your groups:

```
/([a-z]+).*\|\s([0-9]+)/i
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/Q041dv/1)